# I want my slicer in Power BI to show averages instead of number

Tags: powerbi, slicers

I am not sure how to change the slicer so it shows averages for "number of employees." Below example should display 463.5 instead of 462 and 465 from the csv.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbWOJ.png)

I have tried right clicking on the field and in the visualization tab and in the field tab. I have also tried changing the summarization to average.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that you must have a column with the average of employees by geographic area.

You can create a calculated column using AVERAGEX

```
AVERAGEX(manufacturing_data[Geographic Area Name], SUM(manufacturing_data[Number of employees]))
```